# FolioReaderKit throws error when used in Siri Intent extension

Tags: ios-app-extension

I am trying to use FolioReaderKit in my app extensions that I am using for Siri. It is showing me an error "'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.". I have read the apple document and it says that

```
    Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions.
```

So as we can't use shared objects in app extensions, this is the code that is creating the problem:

```
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(mik_findFirstResponder(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I wonder if there is not enough code here to help readers replicate the problem?

Comment: @halfer Just pod FolioReaderKit in your application and create an Intents extension. Now try import FolioReaderKit in your extension. That's it....there's no code involved.